# PHP Defined variable and jQuery $.get

Tags: php, jquery, defined

I defined a variable in PHP

```
define("SOMETHING","Something text");
```

Then I have a PHP file (defined.php):

```
echo SOMETHING;
```

And my jQuery $.get request is:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",   
     url: "/include/defined.php",   
     async: false,
     success : function(text)
     {
         response = text;
     }
});
```

I want to get in variable response "Something text" and not SOMETHING!
Is there a way to do so?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Meaning the value in `text` is `SOMETHING` and not `Something text`? Did you include the file where the constant is defined in `defined.php`?

Comment: looks fine.. any error you have there??

Comment: just echo SOMETHING; in your defined.php

Comment: `SOMETHING` is not a *variable*, it's actually a *constant*. And if you're getting this literal value as text on client-side, means that it has not been defined before the echo.

Comment: why not just open the file: `/include/defined.php` and see what is there? I mean open in browser and see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scope error: SOMETHING is not defined at the moment of the echo call.

Maybe you forgot to include the file with your defined.php?

Comment: Done, spelling mistake in the file name. Thank you so much :)